# Load images in tarball from a link to tensorflow for training CNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, download

I am a newbie in Tensorflow and have hard time figuring out a very simple task. Most of the examples for Tensorflow comes from MNIST and cifar10 which are built into the library, so we don't need to download *.jpg files and convert them to arrays for Tensorflow. I have the following dataset: [17 flower categories](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/data/flowers/17/). it is a tarball that contains 1360 images. There is no labels for images. We can divide it into batches of 80 images that represent each category starting from the first image, so we get 80x17=1360 images. 
I was not able load the dataset from the URL to python. But, I downloaded it to local folder and then loaded using the line:

```
import tarfile
f = tarfile.open("../input/17flowers.tgz")
for member in f.getmembers():
   g = f.extractfile(member)
```

However, this is not helpful in loading images to training my model.
Can you, please, show me a snippet of code that loads the dataset from the link and then loads images to tensorflow for training. Labels should be from 1 to 17 for each 80 consecutive images.
Thanks!

Comment: by the way, I am using kaggle and interestingly, this dataset was not uploaded to kaggle until now.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem by referring to the code and modifying it: https://github.com/changyq12/17_flower_cnn_tensorflow/blob/master/convolutional_network.py